# How to display "from" fields in comments via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to find the id (app-scoped) for someone who has posted a comment on a public page.

For example, I get a list of recent posts/comments on the NY Times page via:

`v2.11/nytimes/feed?fields=comments.limit(10){message,created_time,from},name,message,from&limit=2`

The data returned looks like this:

```
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "message": "Wouldn’t know. Not paying $13/mo for this.",
        "created_time": "2017-12-10T05:57:18+0000",
        "id": "10151412260164999_10151414049324999"
      }
    ],
```

There is no `from` field.  The same is also true if I attempt to view the comment directly using it's id with

`v2.11/10151412260164999_10151414049324999?fields=from,message,created_time`

I have tried using the Facebook Graph API Explorer, using both my User Token, as well as an App Token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since v2.11 of the Graph API, you need a Page Token to get user data of comments: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90

> User information will not be included in GET responses for any objects owned by (on) a Page unless the request is made with a Page access token. This affects all nodes and edges that return data for objects owned by a Page.

In other words: You can only get user information if you manage the Page.

Edit: Since the latests update in the Graph API, you have to get the App [reviewed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) and you must go through Business Verification or Individual Verification. (thanx @Guiman04)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and precise answer.  I see that if I go back to v2.10, the `from` information is present.  So it's available for a limited time only.  ;)

Comment: well, I can't still get the user information with v2.10. any idea?

Comment: are you sure your app works with v2.10 and was not created later with a higher version? also, are you definitely using a page token?

Comment: maybe i do something wrong, trying the same, first get personal access token, then get token for page i manage, then with the second token try to get the "from" in comment, but no luck ?  any step-by-step or gotchas info? what do i do wrong?

i get the page access token ok, and list comments of a post, but "from" never shows up - using the v3.2/{postid}/comments?fields=from,is_hidden,message

Comment: are you 100% sure you are using a page token of your page? btw, that specific question is part of some recent stackoverflow threads. maybe they changed it to protect user data privacy.

Comment: Since the latests update in the Graph API, to get private information from the users, even the author of some public post. You need to get the auth token with the manage_pages scope to get permission to the page itself then get the app reviewed ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review ) and last you must go thru the Business Verification or the Individual Verification. The last is a legal contract to use the info.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are using the accessToken for the page you are trying to get data from, i had same issue, and was resolved by using the correct accessToken for the page.